# Does anyone know what happened to my Croton?

Tags: houseplants

This croton was doing well in my office as of Friday. I came back from the holiday weekend and he looks like he is dying now! Does anyone know what could have caused this? I watered him today to see if that would help. So far it hasn't made too big of a difference. [image]

Comment: It is dry, just water it thoroughly